# Linear regression on 415 files, output just filename, regression coefficient, significance

Tags: r, file, regression

I am a beginner in R, I am learning the basics to analyse some biological data. I have 415 .csv files, each is a fungal species. Each file has 5 columns - (YEAR, FFD, LFD, MEAN, RANGE)

```
    YEAR    FFD LFD RAN MEAN
1   1950    NA  NA  NA  NA
2   1951    NA  NA  NA  NA
3   1952    NA  NA  NA  NA
4   1953    NA  NA  NA  NA
5   1954    NA  NA  NA  NA
6   1955    NA  NA  NA  NA
7   1956    NA  NA  NA  NA
8   1957    NA  NA  NA  NA
9   1958    NA  NA  NA  NA
10  1959    140 141 1   140
11  1960    NA  NA  NA  NA
12  1961    NA  NA  NA  NA
13  1962    NA  NA  NA  NA
14  1963    NA  NA  NA  NA
15  1964    NA  NA  NA  NA
16  1965    155 156 1   155
17  1966    NA  NA  NA  NA
18  1967    NA  NA  NA  NA
19  1968    152 153 1   152
20  1969    NA  NA  NA  NA
21  1970    NA  NA  NA  NA
22  1971    161 162 1   161
23  1972    NA  NA  NA  NA
24  1973    143 144 1   143
25  1974    NA  NA  NA  NA
26  1975    NA  NA  NA  NA
27  1976    NA  NA  NA  NA
28  1977    NA  NA  NA  NA
29  1978    NA  NA  NA  NA
30  1979    NA  NA  NA  NA
31  1980    NA  NA  NA  NA
32  1981    NA  NA  NA  NA
33  1982    155 156 1   155
34  1983    NA  NA  NA  NA
35  1984    NA  NA  NA  NA
36  1985    157 158 1   157
37  1986    170 310 140 240
38  1987    173 274 101 232
39  1988    192 236 44  214
40  1989    234 320 86  277
41  1990    172 287 115 213
42  1991    148 287 139 205
43  1992    140 278 138 206
44  1993    152 273 121 216
45  1994    142 319 177 228
46  1995    261 318 57  287
47  1996    247 315 68  285
48  1997    164 270 106 230
49  1998    186 187 1   186
50  1999    235 236 1   235
51  2000    NA  NA  NA  NA
52  2001    309 310 1   309
53  2002    203 308 105 256
54  2003    140 238 98  189
55  2004    204 313 109 267
56  2005    253 313 60  287
57  2006    247 300 53  279
58  2007    185 295 110 225
59  2008    259 260 1   259
60  2009    296 315 19  309
61  2010    230 303 73  275
62  2011    247 248 1   247
63  2012    206 207 1   206
64  2013    NA  NA  NA  NA
65  2014    250 317 67  271
```

First I would like to see the regression coefficient (slope of the line) for each file, and the significance (p-value) for all of the files.

I can do it individually with:

```
fruit<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
yr<-fruit[,1]
ffd<-fruit[,2]
res<-lm(ffd~yr)
summary(res)
```

when I do this for the data, I get:

```
Call:
lm(formula = ffd ~ yr)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-77.358 -20.858  -5.714  22.494  96.015 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -4162.0710   950.1439  -4.380 0.000119 ***
yr              2.1864     0.4765   4.588 6.55e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 38.75 on 32 degrees of freedom
  (31 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.3968,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.378 
F-statistic: 21.05 on 1 and 32 DF,  p-value: 6.549e-05
```

The only information I need from this at the moment is the regression coefficient (2.1864) and the p-value (6.549e-05)

The perfect output would be if I could get R to cycle through the 415 files, and give an output in the form of a table with 3 columns: filename, regression coefficient, and significance. There would be 415 rows, one for each file.

I would then like to do YEAR~LFD, YEAR~RANGE, and YEAR~MEAN. I am hoping that I can easily edit the code for YEAR~FFD and run it for the other 3 regressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I simulate like 5 csv files, with columns that look like yours:

```
for(i in 1:5){
  tab=data.frame(
      YEAR=1950:2014,
      FFD= rpois(65,100),
      LFD= rnorm(65,100,10),
      RAN= rnbinom(65,mu=100,size=1),
      MEAN = runif(65,min=50,max=150)
  )
  write.csv(tab,paste0("data",i,".csv"))
}
```

Now, we need a vector of all the files in your directory, this will be different for yours, but try to create this somehow using the pattern argument:

```
csvfiles = dir(pattern="data[0-9]*.csv$")
```

So we use three libraries from tidyverse, and I guess each csv file is not so huge, so the code below reads in all the files, group them by the source and performs the regression, note you can use call the columns from the data frame, not having to rename them:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

csvfiles %>% 
map_df(function(i){df = read.csv(i);df$data = i;df}) %>%  
group_by(data) %>% 
do(tidy(lm(FFD ~ YEAR,data=.))) %>% 
filter(term!="(Intercept)")

# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   data [5]
  data      term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 data1.csv YEAR   -0.0228    0.0731    -0.311 0.756  
2 data2.csv YEAR   -0.139     0.0573    -2.42  0.0182 
3 data3.csv YEAR   -0.175     0.0650    -2.70  0.00901
4 data4.csv YEAR   -0.0478    0.0628    -0.762 0.449  
5 data5.csv YEAR    0.0204    0.0648     0.315 0.754
```

You can just change the formula inside `lm(FFD ~ YEAR,data=.)` to get the other regressions

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207135/discussion-on-answer-by-stupidwolf-linear-regression-on-415-files-output-just-f).

Answer (score 4):

The following code will probably work.
I have tested it with your data in two files. The functions that do all the work are these ones:

```
regrFun <- function(DF){
  fit <- lm(DF[[1]] ~ DF[[2]])
  coef(summary(fit))[2, c(1, 4)]
}
regrList <- function(iv, L){
  res <- lapply(seq_along(L), function(i){
    dftmp <- L[[i]]
    cfs <- regrFun(dftmp[c(1, iv)])
    data.frame(file = names(L)[i], Estimate = cfs[1], p.value = cfs[2])
  })
  res <- do.call(rbind, res)
  row.names(res) <- NULL
  res
}
```

Now read in the data files. In the following code line, substitute a common filename part for `"pattern"` in the obvious place.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "pattern")
df_list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
names(df_list) <- filenames
```

And compute the values you want.

```
results_list <- lapply(2:ncol(df_list[[1]]), regrList, df_list)
names(results_list) <- names(df_list[[1]][-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` version, using StupidWolf's csv files layout and names, featuring the requested fields:

```
library(data.table)

input.dir = "/home/user/Desktop/My Folder/" # adjust to your needs
csvfiles <- list.files(path=input.dir, full.names=TRUE, pattern=".*data(.*)\\.csv") # adjust pattern
```

Above, I used a more specific regex pattern, but you could just pick pattern="*.csv" if you want to process all csv files in that folder.

```
# order the files
csvfiles <- csvfiles[order(as.numeric(gsub(".*data(.*)\\.csv", "\\1", csvfiles)))]

# function to read file and return requested columns
regrFun <- function(x){
    DT <- fread(x)
    fit <- lm(FFD ~ YEAR, data=DT)
    return(as.list(c(filename=basename(x), coef(summary(fit))[2, c(1, 4)])))
}

# apply function and rename columns
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(csvfiles, regrFun))
setnames(DT, c("filename", "regression coefficient", "significance"))

DT
```

Result:

```
        filename regression coefficient       significance
  1:   data1.csv     -0.113286713286712 0.0874762832713643
  2:   data2.csv     -0.044449300699302  0.457096760642717
  3:   data3.csv     0.0464597902097902  0.499618510612891
  4:   data4.csv     -0.032473776223776  0.638494798460044
  5:   data5.csv     0.0562062937062939  0.452955919860998
 ---                                                      
411: data411.csv     0.0381555944055959  0.544185411150829
412: data412.csv    -0.0672202797202807  0.314346452751388
413: data413.csv      0.116564685314687 0.0694785724198052
414: data414.csv    -0.0908216783216786  0.110811677724832
415: data415.csv    -0.0282779720279721  0.638766712090455
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a R script that runs on a single file, then run it on every file via the terminal.

The script is simply a .R file with code inside.
To run it on every file you would execute on your terminal something on the lines of (using bash)

```
for file in $(ls yourDataDirectory); do
    Rscript yourScriptFile.R $file >> finalOutput
done
```

This would run the script in yourScriptFile.R on every file in yourDataDircetory and save the output on finalOutput.

The script code itself would be very similar to the one you already wrote, but instead of `file.choose()` you would use the argument passed by the command line, as described [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/passing-arguments-to-an-r-script-from-command-lines/), and you would have to print only the information you're insterested, instead of the output of `summary`.
finalOutput could even be a csv file, if you format the script output correctly.